# How to pass arguments to a function within a function in R?

Tags: r, function, dictionary, arguments

I created the following function:

```r
library(tidyverse)

comb_map <- function(.list, .f = `+`) {
  
  .f <- as_mapper(.f)
  
  l <- length(.list)
  
  combs <- combn(l, 2)
  
  seq_len(dim(combs)[2]) |>
    map(~ .f(.list[[combs[1 ,][.x]]], .list[[combs[2, ][.x]]])) -> out
  
  if (!is.null(names(.list)) &
      length(.list) == length(na.omit(names(.list)))) {
    
    out |>
      set_names(names(.list)[combs[2,]]) |>
      split(names(.list)[combs[1,]]) -> out
  }
  
  if (length(.list) != length(na.omit(names(.list)))) {
    cat('The output list is unnamed if not all of the input list is also unnamed. \n\n')
  }
  
  out
  
}
```

This function applies a function (.f) using the combined elements of a single list.
The function works very well at first:

```r
l <- list(A = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4),
          B = c(2.2, 2.3, 2.5, 2.7),
          C = c(0.6, 0.9, 1.1, 2.3),
          D = c(0.9, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4))

comb_map(.list = l, .f = cor)
```

However, when I add a new number to one of the vectors of the list (suppose it is A). I need to specify a different argument for the parameter 'use' of the function 'cor' (ex."na.or.complete"), but I could not do that. So I have the following error using my function:

```r
l <- list(A = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 3.2),
          B = c(2.2, 2.3, 2.5, 2.7, NA),
          C = c(0.6, 0.9, 1.1, 2.3, NA),
          D = c(0.9, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, NA))

comb_map(.list = l, .f = cor)
```

The error:

[list of NAs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Elrp.png)